# Textarea does not show content in UI even when DOM shows the innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, textarea

My jsp has the following text area:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="30" id="pasted_values"
                                            class="cell98 h15"></textarea>
```

onload of page, im dynamically setting the content this way:

```
$('#pasted_values').text(pastedValuesText);
```

But on page load, the text area is shown empty. But inspect element, HTML and DOM content for the text area element show the value present.

Tried using .val(). But it only seems to work through js the sandbox js console in firebug.
Tried using the textarea shortcut i.e

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="30" id="pasted_values"
                                    class="cell98 h15" />
```

But the above distorts other UI for some strange reason.

Please help.

Comment: can you share your fiddle?

Comment: Try .html() On your code where you set the .text()

Answer (score 2):

Textarea behaves like other html fields after the page is loaded.

```
$('#pasted_values').val(pastedValuesText);
```

Or

```
document.getElementById('pasted_values').value = pastedValuesText;
```

Comment: "html fields" should be "form controls".

Comment: Call it what you want. They're called fields, because it is where the user can play. If you want to try and enforce a definition that is more strict than the English definition then I wish you luck on your crusade.

Comment: You can choose to use the correct term that has a [*specific meaning in the relevant standard*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-control-infrastructure) (this is a technical forum after all), or just make up a name that may or may not be understood. Up to you of course, I was just making a suggestion.

Comment: Lol. I can't believe you shared this. His text field (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#textFieldSelection) may not even be part of a form as you've suggested (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-control-infrastructure). Even when in a form they are fields according to the current html 5 standard. They are still placed in a fieldset when a collection is desired. 

Sorry bud this is RobG standard you're trying to enforce. Like I said you can try and crusade and I wish you luck, but you're crusade should be fought somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working
http://jsfiddle.net/ECFcR/

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="30" id="pasted_values"
                                            class="cell98 h15"></textarea>

$('#pasted_values').text('Hello World!');
```

Is the colour in the textarea the same as background?

What is the value of pastedValuesText?